# How to get all the reviews for the movie from IMDB using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

After using this code in R, I see that a lot of reviews have not been scraped. Although there are more than a thousand reviews, only 53 of them were scraped and the others are blank, I don't know why. Am I missing to add something? I have also tried to put the xpath in the html_nodes(). I got this node i.e. ('.show-more__control') by using selector gadget.

```
library(rvest) 
library(dplyr)
imdb<-read_html('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1825683/reviews?ref_=tt_ql_3')

imdb_nodes<-imdb %>% html_nodes('.show-more__control') %>% html_text()
imdb_nodes
```

Comment: I'd say this is hard to scrape by rvest only. I suggest using RSelenium.

Comment: The page loads additional reviews from pages generated by AJAX like this: `https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1825683/reviews/_ajax?ref_=undefined&paginationKey=g4wp7cbiqeydgyqe66vhrmzyrltm6hjjtzpwzouokkd2gbzgpnt6uck2pe3f5mbkb4dyz23nke7kdaxu4eiwjnbba6vxu`. The `Load More` button uses JS code at `https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/js/collections/user-reviews-2154194008._CB407253794_.js` to generate the `data-key` to get the AJAX links. You can look at the code but I found hard to generate the `data-key` on my own.